# How I can load a Png image from file which have another extension?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, image-conversion, timage

I'm using a TImage component to load some png images, but some of them have the `.imp` extension. I add the *Vcl.Imaging.pngimage* unit to my code and I'm using this code to load the images

```
 if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

But when the LoadFromFile procedure is executed a exception is raised

> Unknown picture file extension (.imp)

these images (.imp) are png files generated by an extenal app and are located in a read-only folder, so rename these files is not a option, the question is How I can load a Png image in a TImage component from a file which have another extension?

Comment: load  it to a stream and then load the image from that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you must register the file format first using the [`TPicture.RegisterFileFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture.RegisterFileFormat) method

Try this

```
TPicture.RegisterFileFormat('imp','imp (png) image file',TPngImage);
```